# Value change range slider HTML5 and ng-repeat AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, range

I'm using a HTML5 range slider to set a value (status) and send it to a db. The problem I'm having now is that when I reload the page the slider and it's value are always set on '50'. The slider is generated inside an ng-repeat from angularjs. When I change the value in the db I see that the 'value' from the slider is changing, but nothing happens with the gui...

Can someone help me with this issue? 
Thanks in advance...

```
<h3 style="text-align: center">{{dim1}}</h3>
<input ng-model="dim1" ng-touchend="dim_switch(node, dim1)" ng-mouseup="dim_switch(node, dim1)" id="dimslider" value="{{parseInt(node.status)}}" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: Use localStorage to set the value and get back same value on reload the application

Comment: `parseInt()` won't evaluate in angular expression, move it to some controller method and call method from UI.

Comment: @anoop - Call it from ngChange ? Tried that approach but it gave me errors and called the function several times, even when there were no changes...

Comment: @RohitJindal It should work realtime and not only on reload (i check db data every ... second and push changed values to the ngrepeat)

Comment: When I remove the ng-model from the input tag it works on page reload... But still not realtime -> i have made also buttons from simple input buttons and those work realtime

Comment: @AlexLogist: what if you do `ng-value="someMethod(node.status)"` and in controller method , `return parseInt(statusParam)`

Comment: @anoop The value from the slider changes when I inspect the element but nothing happens in the GUI...

Comment: @AlexLogist : what is `dim1`? `$scope` property or `ng-repeat` iterator ?

Comment: I will explain:
-I have a h3 that must display the slider value (live when changing/dragging the slider and the current value).
-The range slider gets a value from the ng-repeat (node.status) and must update (also gui) when a database value is also changed (this happens, but the GUI does not update, only the back-end value, don't know why) ...
- dim1 is only used to make the connection between the slider and the h3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ng-repeat` creates a new child scope.([doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)).

hence your `$soppe.dim1` gets overidden by the new child scope. So wrap your property by hierarchical model to leverage javascript prototypical inheritance., and persist your $scope property.

like `$scope.slider = {dim1 : ''}` and use it in HTML like : `{{slider.dim1}}`.

**further** : `parseInt()` won't evaluate in angular expression, move it to some controller method.

Like: `ng-value="someMethod(node.status)"` and from controller method `return parseInt(statusParam)`

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but i have a lot of elements in my ng-repeat... + The parseInt i removed by using an int value in my database and not a string anymore...

Comment: @AlexLogist: then add some `sliderValue` variable in your `ng-repeat` dataArray, like `ng-repeat = "data in dataArray"` and in html `{{data.sliderValue}}`.

Comment: Still not updating the Gui

Comment: @AlexLogist: please create some plunker\fiddle to reproduce issue, or update mine [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sewLpq5f/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the HTML5 range slider does not use the "value" attribute -> problem solved with a combination of the given solution !